Create model for manufacturing defect detection using python
Has anyone done some work on manufacturer defect detection? I need some input on this. I have done some research and found some examples like TensorFlow/Keras and CNN, but I need some real-time experience if someone has already explored it. Thanks in advance.
Have tried following
convolutional neural network (CNN) to classify images
TensorFlow/Keras for image classification
I am looking for input if I am going in correct direction along with some inputs how to make such modles production ready terms of error

I'm afraid it is not possible to answer this question as too many information are missing. E.g., we don't know exactly what kind of data type/modailty "defect detection" encompasses. Is this image data? Or is this just a column of scalar numbers? The probability of getting a useful response increases drastically with the degree of details by which you describe your problem.

Apology for this, it's an mage data . Thank you so much for your response. I believe you answers will be going to help me learning and making model robust @BanDoP
